# How does a simple CTE work?

Tags: sql, oracle, common-table-expression

Say, I have a short query.

```
with test_cte as(
select *
from table1
where conditions1
)
select *
from table2
inner join test_cte
on conditions2
where conditions3
```

Am I right to assume that the query first goes through `test_cte` to filter the rows based on `conditions1`, stores the data somewhere, and after again goes through the remaining rows from `test_cte` when joining to table2? where does it store data then? RAM? Or is this equivalent to

```
select *
from table2
inner join table1
on conditions2
where conditions3 and conditions1
```

but easier to read with big queries?

Comment: Think of the cte as a temp table that disappears as soon as you've used the "Table" once.

Comment: @Snowlockk - Where did you come up with that? The CTE may be used either as a temp table or an inline view (a subquery), the optimizer will decide which one; and the CTE does not disappear as soon as it's used **once**.

Comment: Call your cte once then afterwards call it again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your CTE is just a syntax variation of a Derived Table (which Oracle calls *Inline View*):

```
select *
from table2
inner join
 (
   select *
   from table1
   where conditions1
 ) AS test_cte
on conditions2
where conditions3
```

A decent optmizer will not always create the result of the CTE/DT first (only if it's too complex), so in your case the plan should be similar to your 2nd query. Simply compare the plan of both queries.

And as you noticed CTEs/DTs are mainly used to simplify writing of more complex queries by splitting it into smaller groups of logic or because you need something you can't write in a single level, like an Aggregate on top of a Windowed Aggregate.

Comment: Actually I don't think simplification of complex queries is the main use case of CTEs, at least not in Oracle.

Answer (score 1):

> "where does it store data then? RAM? "

That depends. The Optimizer will assess the cost of the subquery; if teh cost is high enough (maybe due to complexity or size) then Oracle will materialize it as a global temporary table and write it to disk. So only use CTEs when there's a definite benefit from doing so.

One benefit is that we can reuse the CTE result multiple times in the main query. So extending your example:

```
with test_cte as(
    select *
    from table1
    where conditions1
)
select *
from table2
inner join test_cte
    on conditions2
where table1.whatever not in ( select whatever
                               from test_cte
                               where conditions3)
```

Here you're querying `table1` once but using its records twice.

Another advantage of CTEs is that we can chain them:

```
with test_cte as(
    select *
    from table1
    where conditions1
)
, next_cte as (
   select t1.*
           , t23.*
   from test_cte t1
        join table23 t23
        on t1.id = t23.id)
select * 
from next_cte
```

This can be useful in breaking up complex queries into easier to understand chunks. However, in is important for us to be sure we're cleverer than the optimizer before embarking on this route!

Another use for the WITH clause is writing recursive queries. Since 11gR2 this construct has allowed us to navigate parent-child relationships without using Oracle's hierarchical query syntax. [Find out more](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_10002.htm#BCEJGIBG).

```
with cte (id, parent_id, lvl) as
     ( select id, p_id, 0 as lvl
       from t23
       where p_id is null
       union all
       select t23.id, t23.p_id, cte.lvl + 1
       from cte
            join t23 
            on cte.id = t23.p_id)
select *
from cte
order by lvl, id
/
```

Comment: I do not believe the size of the CTE's result set is a factor that determines if the CTE is materialzed

Comment: @BobC - so what do you believe? I have rewritten that sentence because size is not the only factor. The optimizer assesses the cost of the subquery and decides whether to materialize it at runtime. I believe the size of the result set is a contributor to the cost of a query but I admit I haven't seen a definitive explanation of what rules the optimizer applies. If you have a link please post it, as I'm interested to learn more.

Comment: The CTE transformations are not cost based. So basically, if you reference the CTE more than once (or use the MATERIALIZE hint), then it will be materialized.